# how to execute brother dcp135 printer driver

Tags: rpm

How do I run an executable file (a .rpm file), in this case a printer driver?

Comment: Generally, that depends on how you downloaded it, and what instructions came with it. Unlike Windows drivers, Linux drivers are rarely ready-made executables that you just have to run; instead you may have to install it by issuing a `dpkg` command, or even more complicated actions. However: you say that it is a .rpm file. That means that it is not intended for Ubuntu systems; Ubuntu uses the software installation format .deb. So please look around on the driver download page where you got the .rpm file from, to see if there is a .deb file available as well.

Comment: rpm files can be converted to deb using alien. However in this case I think your better off using the approved method of installing the printer under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install it over a rpm and not over the normal way (cups whit driver detecton) you can use this programm to convert your rpm to deb https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto